# 'Cannot connect to App Store' on mobile network

Tags: network, ios-appstore

When I try accessing the App Store when I'm not connected to a wireless network, it shows 'Cannot connect to App Store'; I've already re-applied the settings for mobile data, but that didn't help. The weird thing is that it seems to be downloading update info (this morning I downloaded all the updates via wifi, and right now it shows me two new ones although I haven't been connected to wifi for a few hours).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[iPhone 5s, iOS 9.2 beta]

Comment: It's likely because you are on a Beta program.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try logout and login into `iTunes & App Store` on you phone.

Comment: I've already tried that, and just did it again, sadly it still isn't working.

Comment: hmm, as it is beta you'll probably have to apply the current updates on wifi.

Comment: Well, I think I'm actually able to do updates when I'm not connected to wifi, but the tabs line Highlights/Charts say 'Cannot connect to App Store'

Comment: hmm, any reason for not trying updating using iTunes on Mac?